# 401 unauthorized from maven when publishing to gitlab artifactory

Tags: maven, gitlab, artifactory

I am facing an issue when trying to publish an artifact in private gitlab repository. I am using maven and I authenticated using personal access token. When I run  `mvn deploy -s ~/.m2/settings.xml` I get the following error  `Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact ... 401 Unauthorized`

My settings.xml file looks like this.

```
<servers>
    <server>
      <id>gitlab-maven</id>
      <configuration>
        <httpHeaders>
          <property>
            <name>personal-token</name>
            <value>mytoken</value>
          </property>
        </httpHeaders>
      </configuration>
    </server>
  </servers>
```

I've also tried changing it to

```
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>gitlab-maven</id>
            <username>username</username>
            <password>pass</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
```

but that didn't help. And here is my `pom` publishing part

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>gitlab-maven</id>
            <url>https://gitlab.mycompany.com/api/v4/projects/92/packages/maven</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>gitlab-maven</id>
            <url>https://gitlab.mycompany.com/api/v4/projects/92/packages/maven</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>gitlab-maven</id>
            <url>https://gitlab.mycompany.com/api/v4/projects/92/packages/maven</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
```

Is there anything that I'm missing? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fixed this by changing  property in the settings file to `Private-Token` (I was using actual name of the token previously)

Comment: Searched up and down and it never occurred to me, that the name can't be random. Thanks a lot.

Comment: GitLab documentation seems to be wrong: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/maven_repository/#edit-the-client-configuration

Funny thing that it mentions it differently right below, https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/maven_repository/#edit-the-client-configuration

Comment: @LeoFuso seems that it is fixed, i do not see any wrong naming by now

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem but for a different reason. 
my idea (intellij with built in maven plugin) was using different settings file (C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\.m2\settings.xml) from the one i configured the server (local maven installation on a different path).
to fix this go to: File -> Settings (on windows Ctrl + Alt + s) -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven -> User settings file.
mark the check box for Override and direct to the correct path.
hopefully it will save someone's time...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Clear enough. I had my `settings.xml` inside the project. As soon as I moved it to `.m2/settings.xml` it worked.

Answer (score 3):

As [Nane Petrosyan pointed out,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68904217/7473935) the name which must be specified is not the token name nor the Gitlab username. The actual name also depends on what kind of token you are using.

See the official documentation to know which name to use, section *Custom HTTP header*: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/maven_repository/#custom-http-header

- For [personal token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html) (user specific token): Private-Token.
- For [deploy token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_tokens/) (repository specific token): Deploy-Token.
- And for [CI Job token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/ci_job_token.html) (temporary tokens that Gitlab creates for the duration of a Gitlab build): Job-Token.

In the event you intend to deploy directly from Gitlab pipeline, the only kind of token you can use are the CI Job token, as pointed out in Gitlab documentation, section *Create Maven packages with GitLab CI/CD*: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/maven_repository/#create-maven-packages-with-gitlab-cicd

Here's an example of a local settings.xml with a personal token:

```
<settings
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd">

  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>gitlab-maven</id>
      <configuration>
        <httpHeaders>
          <property>
            <name>Private-Token</name>
            <value>[your generated personal token here]</value>
          </property>
        </httpHeaders>
      </configuration>
    </server>
  </servers>

</settings>
```

Comment: Although group tokens exist, I haven't seen any mention of them for this use case yet.

Answer (score 0):

In case this might help someone:

Once you reach the "[mvn deploy](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/maven_repository/index.html#publish-a-package)" step in the gitlab docs and find yourself struggling with **401 Unauthorized** error, running the deploy command with `-s` or `--settings` flag like so:

`mvn deploy -s settings.xml` (the argument to the -s flag is the path to your project *settings.xml* file)

Solves the issue (at least for me) by using the user specified settings file instead of the default one stored in .m2 folder.

(I found solution in [this](https://youtu.be/ui2nNBwN35c?t=396) video)